# Is there a way to remove the time limit in Pikmin 3 mission mode?

Tags: pikmin-3

In Pikmin 3, I want to do the mission slowly with my kid.  We would like to take our time and have fun. The time limit is too short for that. Is there a way to remove the time limit in mission mode?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, no. They didn't really design the game for how you'd like to play it. Which is a shame; I'd love to play that way with my daughter too.

In that mode, you're trying to get as many fruits and enemies beaten as you can in the time limit, going for your best score. It's actually really difficult and takes severel tries, practice, and planning to beat the clock. If you do manage to beat the clock, time remaining gives you points.

So I guess my best advice is to work together to get better scores. Maybe someday you can beat the clock. I think when you do so, you get a little "Captain" crown or star or something (I forget).

Comment: Thanks ! I beat the clock with my girlfriend (we're a great team yeah!)